# Phrases avec « Falloir faire avec »

Tags: expressions, formulation

> Les résultats ne sont pas stables pour le moment, mais il va falloir faire avec.

J'ai rencontré cette phrase dans un mail. Je me demande si elle est correcte.

N'est-il pas plus correct d'écrire :

> Les résultats ne sont pas stables pour le moment, mais il va falloir en faire avec.

ou bien :

> Les résultats ne sont pas stables pour le moment, mais il va falloir faire avec cela.

?

Comment: Plutôt *faire avec **ça*** pour rester dans le même registre.

Comment: Le troisième est peu naturel (quoiqu'un peu moins pire avec 'ça' que 'cela').

Comment: "Faire avec" est un idiome. C'est donc correct par définition. Voir aussi la réponse d'LPH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La première et la dernière sont  correctes mais pas la seconde.

Le pronom « en » dans la phrase a la fonction de COD parce que « faire (quelque chose) avec (quelque chose) » est transitif ; comme il faut un antécédent, ce ne peut être que « résultats » et cela n'a pas de sens (faire les résultats); avec un autre verbe, par exemple, « s'accommoder **de** (quelque chose) », il n'y a plus de problème ;

- Les résultats ne sont pas stables pour le moment, mais il va falloir s'en accommoder.